# drupal_set_title not working in module form

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I´m trying to learn Drupal 8. So now, I´m "building" forms.
I created a module.
INSIDE mymodule\src\Form
I have form1.php

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class form1 extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'myform1';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Your name'),
    '#maxlength' => 30,
    );
    $form['Lastname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Your lastname'),
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form;
  }
```

And WORKS...
But when I want to put a title to the page, in my case and linked to my_module.routing.yml, 127.0.0.1/form1 using

```
...
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

drupal_set_title(t('This is a Title'));

    $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Your name'),
    '#maxlength' => 30,
    );
...
```

I receive the following ERROR:

**ERROR:**
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Drupal\mymodule\Form\drupal_set_title() in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalwebsite\modules\custom\mymodule\src\Form\form1.php on line 16

**An the line 16 is:**

```
drupal_set_title(t('This is a Title'));
```

So the problem is with the title. I tried to resolve it but I could not.
Anyone know why?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.drupal.org/node/2067859, drupal_set_title() was removed in D8.  Have you tried the alternate method that's mentioned in that link, like this:

`$form['#title'] = $this->t('This is a Title');`

Comment: You made my day! I do not know why the books that I´m reading mix 6/7/8. Thanks a lot!